# Dynamic wait in winapp driver

Tags: selenium, webdriverwait, python-appium, winappdriver

I am using winapp-driver with python for to connect wirelless ssid in windows client. There i am using implicit and explicit wait but both are not working. Seems driver is running on default timeout even if implicit wait is set to 5 sec

```
    def wait_until(self, element_type,element_name, parent=None, timeout=EXPLICIT_WAIT):
        if parent is None:
            parent = self.driver

        try:
            WebDriverWait(parent, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((eval("By." + element_type), element_name)))
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
```

This is how i am using the function:

```
        ntwrk_icn = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id(NETWORK_ICON_ID)
        start = time.time()
        if self.wait_until("NAME", NETWORK_WINDOW, timeout=5):
            print("Network window already opened, close and open again")
            ntwrk_icn.click()
        print("wait time")
        print(time.time()-start)
```

Execution for this step is taking 22 seconds
Also implicit wait is not working. For find_elements is is going to default 30 secs

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#init function

    def __init__(self, driverIp, driverPort=4723):
        self.server_address = 'http://{}:{}/wd/hub'.format(driverIp, str(driverPort))
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps["app"] = "Root"
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=self.server_address, desired_capabilities= desired_caps)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(IMPLICIT_WAIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "EC.presence_of_element_located", try using simple .Displayed property for the wait?

Comment: That can be used... but the poblem is timeout i am giving doesn't seems to be accepted. I want to control wait time